# ajax, modal window, переход по ссылке

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

Имеется разметка

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => item.Id)</td>
        <th>@Html.DisplayFor(x => item.ManInfo.Initals)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayFor(x => item.Post)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayFor(x => item.Departament.Name)</th>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Редактировать", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Полные данные", "Details", new { id = item.Id }, new { id = "empItem" }) |
            @if (User.IsInRole("admin"))
            {
                @Html.ActionLink("Удалить", "Delete", new { id = item.Id }, new { onclick = "return confirm('Вы уверены?');" })
            }
        </td>
    </tr>
}
...
<div id="Dialog" class="modal fade">
<div id="dialogContent" class="modal-dialog"></div></div>
```

И скрипт

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    $("#empItem").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.get(this.href, function (data) {
            $('#dialogContent').html(data);
            $('#Dialog').modal('show');
        });
    });
});
```

По клику должно отобразиться модальное окно и контентом, который вернет контроллер.

Весь этот код находится в PartialView. После 1 клика отображается модальное окно. Но при 2 клике на другую ссылку (сл. запись в таблице) - идет переход по ссылке и открывается новая страница. А должно опять открыться всплывающее окошко.

В чем проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос был решен явной установкой обработчика

```
<a href="#/" onclick = "myClickHandler('@item.Id)">Полные данные</a>

function myClickHandler(id) {
    $.get('/MyController/Details/' + id, function (data) {
        $('#dialogContent').html(data);
        $('#Dialog').modal('show');
    });
}
```